# error: password authentication failed for user "myuser"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, debian

If I have a record in /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf which specifically trusts my specific user

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             myuser                                trust
```

Since I'm on debian I restart postgresql like this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Here is my entire source file testing this out:

```
const pg = require('pg');
const connectionString = "postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost/mydbname";

const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM USERS');
query.on('end', () => { client.end(); });
```

and this is the error I consistently get:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/myuser/webserver/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/myuser/webserver/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/webserver/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

It's also worth noting that doing the following works:

```
psql -h localhost -U myuser mydb
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) states, `local` is only for UNIX socket connections, while you are establishing a TCP connection to `localhost`.

Use a line like this:

```
host    all    myuser    127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

to trust all connections from `localhost` using IPv4 (use the adress `::1/128` for IPv6).

Comment: It should work fine. Check the PostgreSQL server log to see where the problem is.

Comment: When I plaintext my password and choose password as the authentication method it works, but when I change this to MD5 it doesn't work.

I've also tried putting the md5 hash in the url and that doesn't work either. what should the password url look like?

Comment: You should describe what you mean by "doesn't work" - what is the PostgreSQL log entry if you enable `log_connections`? You should not use the MD5 hash as password, but the original password you supplied. What is your URL? If you want to put the password there, it should look like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret`.

Comment: not working in ubuntu 20.04. Also tried to make all the connection trust. still dont work