# Why application in Azure Container Instance cannot connect to Azure SQL DB for PostgreSQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-container-instances

I have Python application in Azure Container Instance, which tries establish connection to Azure DB for PostgreSQL, but failing. Azure DB firewall is open for Azure services. Connection works fine, when application is connecting from local machine docker.

I wonder what is the problem?

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
'sales.Customers' table is unavailable - sleeping
* Could not resolve host: hslotp
* Closing connection 0
OTP is unavailable - sleeping
```

Comment: Please Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426652/error-password-authentication-failed-for-user-myuser and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131129/psql-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user thread it may help you.

Comment: can you share the connection string format you are trying, some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the ports match, here is something you can verify from [Troubleshoot connection issues to Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues#steps-to-resolve-persistent-connectivity-issues)

make sure you have the latest of `psycopg2` release or atleast above `2.8.0`

Also, the connection string should looks like below. Make sure you get Server name and login details from Azure portal.

```
postgresql://user:password@container_name:5432?sslmode=disable
```

Refer: [thon to connect and query data in Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-python)